# Contracted Bianchi Identity for FLRW Metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to verify that the *Contracted Bianchi Identity* $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}=0$ holds for the Friedmann-Lemaitre-Robertson-Walker (FLRW) metric,
$$g_{00}=-1,g_{i0}=0,g_{ij}=a^2(t)\delta_{ij}$$
and $G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R$.

I have no problem with the spatial part, i.e., I can show that,
$$\nabla_j G^{ij}=0$$

However, I am unable to show that,
$$\nabla_\mu G^{\mu0}=0$$
Since the $G_{\mu\nu}$'s are diagonal, this should boil down to,
$$\nabla_0 G^{00}=G^{00}_{\,\,\,\,,0}+\Gamma^0_{\mu0}G^{\mu0}+\Gamma^0_{\mu0}G^{0\mu}$$
The Christoffel symbols are 0, and I end up with,
$$\nabla_0 G^{00}=G^{00}_{\,\,\,\,,0}=\frac{6\dot{a}}{a^3}\bigg(a\ddot{a}-\dot{a}^2\bigg)$$

I suspect I am missing something or making some really stupid mistake somewhere. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

EDIT: Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

**EDIT (Resolution):**

I was jumping the gun by implying that $\nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}=0$ implies,
$$\nabla_0 G^{00}=0\quad\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad\quad \nabla_j G^{ij}=0.$$ This is obviously not true, since
$$\nabla_\mu G^{\mu0}=\nabla_0 G^{00}+\text{other terms involving }G^{ij}$$
And these other terms involving $G^{ij}$ precisely cancel $\nabla_0 G^{00}$ to give $0$.

Comment: I think I figured out the mistake. I will write a detailed answer as soon as I am certain.